# ubuntu superuser got corrupted

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, sudoers

I was trying to save times to type password for `sudo` because one of my scripts had to be randomly repeated quite often.  I googled some information about how to bypass typing password and applied to my server.  Now the sudo account is corrupted and all the users on server can not use `sudo`.  How can I fix this?

What I did:

- I created `mysudoers` in `/etc/sudoers.d/`

  `sudo vim /etc/sudoers.d/mysudoers`
- Added my account in `mysudoers`

  `rna ALL = NOPASSWD: ~/scripts/getLog`
- save & exit
- chmod

  `sudo chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/mysudoers`

Error log when I type `sudo` :

```
rna@rna-P580:/etc/sudoers.d$ sudo                                                               
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/mysudoers: syntax error near line 0 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/mysudoers near line 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

**Edit.**

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into single user mode and remove the offending file.
If I recall correctly, Ubuntu has a `recovery mode` by default in the grub boot menu, this will boot into a single user environment as root where you can remove the file.

Use that to boot up, and remove the file, then reboot again to boot back into the normal environment.

In future, when you're modifying `sudo`'s configuration files, **always** have a root shell open (`sudo -i`) so that you can remove / edit files that don't work.

Comment: what does `-i` do?

Comment: `sudo -i` starts a root shell essentially

Comment: ill study more about that later. thanks for the answer @Lawrence

Comment: Oh I almost forgot to ask. Could you tell me what I did wrong up there?

Comment: The line should be `rna ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:~/scripts/getLog` - notice that there's no spaces on either side of the `=`.

Comment: Rather than (or in addition to) opening a root shell, a better approach is to always use visudo to edit a sudoers file.  You can edit a stand-alone file using `visudo -f /path/to/file`, and you can also check a file for syntax issues using `visudo -c -f somefile`.  The `visudo` command uses the `$EDITOR` variable, which, on Ubuntu, points at the editor alternative, configured using `update-alternatives --config editor` (use `--display`  instead of `--config` to see what it currently points to).